# Creating executable without relocations in Visual Studio

Tags: visual-studio, visual-c++, compilation, portable-executable

Why do I care? I'm working on security related application, and it is signed. Relocations mess up the signature, so it can't be verified while running.

And it is not like I need relocations. everything can be done relatively. a bit slower maybe.

how can I convince the compiler to emit code without relocations?

Visual Studio 2015, C++ and nasm for some parts, x64.

Edit: clarifying, I still need it to be position-independent. as I'm not in control on where the program will be loaded. just by using relative access and not relocations.

Comment: in this case you must not use any static imports too (import mess up the signature)

Comment: write postion independed code is possible, but small enough and very restricted. and you need very deep internal knowledge for this. however for x64, because it primary use relative addressing, this more easy compare x86

Answer (score 3):

Try to specify the `/FIXED` flag.

According to the docs (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/build/reference/fixed-fixed-base-address?view=vs-2015):

> When /FIXED is specified, LINK does not generate a relocation section in the program. At run time, if the operating system is unable to load the program at the specified address, it issues an error message and does not load the program.

Comment: Nice, but I still need the program to be position independent. so this solution won't work for me.

Comment: Ah! I'm not sure cl supports generating PE binaries with position-independent code, though (that is, I'm _pretty_ sure it can't do that, and relocations are the only option if you need it to be position-independent).